# How to show name instad of id in django ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a ForeignKey to itself.

models.py

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    important_name = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='first', verbose_name='Very Important Name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_from_object(self)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]
```

And when i want to show my data with **DetailView** CBV in view it show id instead of name.

views.py

```py
class DetailPerson(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'panel/detail_person.html'
```

detail_person.html

```
<table class="table">
    {% for label, value in object.get_fields %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ label }}</td>
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[image: template img]

How can i show name instead of id?

Comment: What you get in `object.get_fields`

Comment: @shafik I added it

Comment: What you value you input for `name`

Comment: @shafik any string like 'john'

Comment: Can you debug in the template? It looks it's Okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can use getattr instead of value_from_object, which will return us the related instance of `Person` instead of an ID.

```py
    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.verbose_name, getattr(self, field.name)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]
```

example:

```py
from base.models import Person
a = Person.objects.first()
a.get_fields()
```

Returns
`[('ID', 1), ('name', 'Joe'), ('Very Important Name', <Person: Bob>)]`

Now, we may access all of `Bob`'s attributes in the template as well, if the need arose.