# How to show name instead of id with foreighkey with django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django application. And a foreign relationship. But the api calls shows the id instead of the name. But I want to show the name instead of the id.

So this is the property:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='animals', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="test")
```

and serializer:

```
class SubAnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description',"category","pet_list", 'images' ]
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

so this is part of the api call:

```
"animals": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Vicuña",
            "description": "kjhkkhkhkjhjkhj Hello",
            "category": 6,
            "pet_list": "D",
            "images": "http://192.168.1.135:8000/media/media/photos/animals/mammal.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Goudhamster",
            "description": "khkjh",
            "category": 6,
            "pet_list": "C",
            "images": "http://192.168.1.135:8000/media/media/photos/animals/imgbin_dog-grooming-puppy-cat-pet-png_I7rLPen.png"
        }
    ],
```

And I googled something ofcourse. So I found this:

[How to show name instad of id in django ForeignKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219330/how-to-show-name-instad-of-id-in-django-foreignkey)

But it doesn't exactly fit what I am looking for.

Question: how to show name instead of id in api call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a [**`SlugRelatedField`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class SubAnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='name', queryset=Category.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'category', 'pet_list', 'images']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

In order to write, the `name` field in `Category` should be unique, and preferrably have a `db_index=True`.

Answer (score 0):

define a field in your serializer and use its `source` attribute like this:

```
class SubAnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.CharField(source='category.name', read_only=True) # <==== 

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description',"category_name","pet_list", 'images' ]
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

Comment: The main downside with using `source='category.name'` is that it only works in the read direction, whereas the write direction is not. Usually the idea of a serializer is to work bi-directional.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Suppose we have one serializer for read and write. In that case, (we usually think about validation for `writing` more) When we are reading data the serializer (read-and-write)operation will check for reading data too, if we don't care about it, we'll see performance issues later.  the best approach is a separate read-and-write serializer. the way that pydantic and fastapi do. in your case, because slugify has overhead for its operation, then it slows down the reading data

Comment: what overhead: it will make a query to fetch the item with the `name` (the term slug is a bit of a misnomen), and validate that. That seems like a sensical way to do, otherwise it would use a `name` for which there is no `Category` available. It does not "slugify" and definitely not processes each record. Separating read and write looks like horrible code design (this is exactly the use case of lenses, which provide this in a monadic structure).

Comment: check it please(drf documentation): `By default this field is read-write, although you can change this behavior using the read_only flag.

When using SlugRelatedField as a read-write field, you will normally want to ensure that the slug field corresponds to a model field with unique=True.`. The main question is, Why do I need SlugRelatedField for reading this field, why don't we have to use charfield or other field types, If both are the same, why they defined it in DRF.

Comment: why would we need that? It simply can inspect the type of the `slug_field` of the related model if we want to derive its type. Furthermore this is not a simple attribute, we serialize (part) of a relation, so the an different toolkit should be used: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: The field is indeed writable, for example a PATCH request can then change the name of the category, which might be an (unwanted) side-effect, sinde this allows changing the category, when making a patch request for a `SubAnimal` object.

Comment: Hey man, the question didn't say anything about category structures. But we suppose the name is a slugfield. In your case, your solution is read-only too(just for reading), You can't use it for writing too. please check it, I checked it now.

Comment: no, in a `SugRelatedField`, you specify a `slug_field` and either `read_only=True`, or `queryset`. So that means you can make a POST request with `"category:" "somecategoryname"`. If there is a `Category` with `'somecategoryname'` as `name` for `Category`, it will assign that category to the `SubAnimal` in this case.

Comment: This is a semantical difference with `source='category.name'`, which can indeed be writable, but the effect is different: in that case it will not work when you *create* a `SubAnimal`, but it will work if you edit (update) a `SubAnimal`: it will assign a new name to the related `Category`, so effectively changing the `name` of the `Category` object whereas the category reference remains the same.

Comment: but we can't change the name or other fields of a category in these systems. if we can change it, we have to use a tag system.

Comment: @HrdiFarhadi: we can, by making the `CharField` not read-only. In that case we can use the serializer in write mode, and save `someanimal.category.save()` this will then update the name, that is exactly what is a bit misleading with a dotted style of `source`. That it has a side effect that it sets an attribute (in this case the name) of a category if it used in write mode, whereas one would expect that it re-links the `SubAnimal` to a different `Category`.

Comment: There was a misunderstanding about my last comment. we can't change the category name when we're editing(adding) the animals or products or anything else in a business model design. if we decide to edit the category fields when we want to edit or add a new model(animal, product, ...) we should use tags. The category model should be populated after launching the app or website, and the admins only can edit it (db and bussiness design).

Comment: but if your serializer would drop the `read_only=True`, it will do exactly that, altering the `name` of the `category`. If the `SlugRelatedField` is writable, it will just link the animal to a different `Category`, which seems something a POST/PUT/PATCH item might want to allow.